# JS How to handle this JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have data like this:

```
{
"1":{
    "id":"1",
    "boarding":"",
    "atak":"3",
    "pw":4,
    "zwrotnosc":3,
    "marynarze":130,
    "zolnierze":0},
 "2":{
    "id":"2",
    "boarding":"",
    "atak":"5",
    "pw":4,
    "zwrotnosc":4,
    "marynarze":0,
    "zolnierze":222}
}
```

I tried for (i in data), or for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) but it's wrong.

It would be nice to have something like php foreach and or handle it like array data[1][pw]

EDIT:

When I do for loop I got like 194 iterations and data[i] holds single char from data.

EDIT2:

This is my data before json reponse:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [boarding] => 
        [atak] => 2
        [pw] => 4
        [zwrotnosc] => 4
        [marynarze] => 146
        [zolnierze] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [boarding] => 
        [atak] => 5
        [pw] => 5
        [zwrotnosc] => 5
        [marynarze] => 0
        [zolnierze] => 250
    )

)
```

I use

```
echo json_encode($players);
```

EDIT3:

It looks like this:
http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4798/screenwlz.png

JSON looks ok:
http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2871/screenmuj.png

EDIT: SOLVED

Ok. Thanks

It helped:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

for (i in data){
   // code
}
```

Comment: First of all, `data` is an Object, not an array, so it doesn't have the `.length` property.
Secondly, I tried the `for...in` loop and it worked well

Comment: Please add the code that does `data = something`

Comment: I don't get it... `data["1"]["pw"]` should work (mind the quotes). Does it not?

Comment: @Salman A: data["1"]["pw"] == undefined

Comment: @Esailija: I don't exactly know what you mean

Comment: @user1489546: Can you post the line where you assign something to `data`; I mean the line that says `data = ...`?

Comment: The answer posted by @Esailija was in fact correct in a way... you had a JSON string all the time; not a JavaScript object. You have to do a `data = JSON.parse(response);`. Thanks for confusing everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just don't realize that JS `for` iterates on keys.

```
for(var key in data) {
    var value = data[key];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work.
I put console.log(value+' '+key); in place of "do stuff" and got something like:
{ 0

" 1

1 2

" 3

: 4

{ 5

" 6

i 7

d 8

" 9

: 10

" 11

1 12

" 13

, 14

" 15

b 16

o 17

Comment: @user1489546 Use `data = JSON.parse(data)` and THEN run the loop in this answer. You are obviously using it on a string.

Comment: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: @user1489546 I'm not sure what you used until you add the code where you assign `data`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run nested `for` loops:

```
// var data = <?php echo json_encode($players); ?>;
//            ^                                  ^
//            +----------------------------------+---- no quotes
var data = {
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "boarding": "",
        "atak": "3",
        "pw": 4,
        "zwrotnosc": 3,
        "marynarze": 130,
        "zolnierze": 0
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "boarding": "",
        "atak": "5",
        "pw": 4,
        "zwrotnosc": 4,
        "marynarze": 0,
        "zolnierze": 222
    }
}
for (var i in data) {
    for (var j in data[i]) {
        console.log("data[" + i + "][" + j + "]", data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I got:
data[0][0] {
data[1][0] "
data[2][0] 1
data[3][0] "
data[4][0] :
data[5][0] {
data[6][0] "
data[7][0] i
data[8][0] d
data[9][0] "
(...)
data[188][0] }

Comment: I don't get it. Where are the indices 0, 3, 4, ...,  188 coming from? I forgot to mention you first need to do a `vat data = {"1":...};`

Comment: There is something wrong with my JSON data. When copy and execute this code it works. But doesn't with my response data.